# MAUI Graphics Color to Native Android/iOS Color

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

I was creating a custom control when I realised there are no direct helper methods where I could manually find a converter that does a `Maui.Graphics.Color` to `Android.Graphics.Color` or a `UIKIT.UIColor`

Am I missing something? In XF we had methods like

```
XFColor.ToUIColor();
XFColor.ToAndroidColor();
```

Please let me know if I am missing something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You can now find an extension method to do this in the following namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
color.ToPlatform(); // here color is a Maui.Graphics.Color
```

**OG answer:**

Well, I could not find a direct helper method/class to do this so I just created some extension methods to do this:

```
#if ANDROID
using NativeColor = Android.Graphics.Color;
#endif
#if IOS
using NativeColor = UIKit.UIColor;
#endif

public static class Extensions
    {

    /// <summary>
        /// Get native color from maui color 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="color"></param>
        /// <returns>native Color</returns>
        public static NativeColor ToNativeColor(this Color color)
        {
            var hexCode = color.ToHex();
            NativeColor nativeColor;
#if ANDROID
            nativeColor=  Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(hexCode);
#endif
#if IOS
            nativeColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear.FromHex(hexCode);
#endif
            return nativeColor;
        }

#if IOS
        public static UIColor FromHex(this UIColor color, string hex)
        {
            int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;

            if (hex.Contains("#"))
                hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

            switch (hex.Length)
            {
                case 2:
                    r = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    g = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    b = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    a = 255;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    r = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    g = int.Parse(hex.Substring(1, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    b = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    a = 255;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    r = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    g = int.Parse(hex.Substring(1, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    b = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    a = int.Parse(hex.Substring(3, 1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    r = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    g = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    b = int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    a = 255;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    r = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    g = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    b = int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    a = int.Parse(hex.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                    break;
            }

            return UIColor.FromRGBA(r, g, b, a);
        }
#endif

    }
```

I hope this helps someone, Not sure if this is the best solution so if you have something better please let me know so I can update this :)

Comment: Should `using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;` work in a .NET 6 Android project?

Comment: I guess does it not?

Comment: It does not appear to work. I take it this is for cross platform MAUI projects where you need to customize some Android/iOS behaviours? .NET Android apps don't seem to benefit from this as of yet.

Comment: You have a .Net Android app and you are using `Maui.Graphics.Color` in it? But why?

Comment: Is there anything to say you can't? Numerous docs indicate you can use Maui.Essentials in .Net platform apps, as well as other Maui namespaces.

Comment: I mean you can bro, it's just something that didn't make sense to me. Anyway you might wanna make sure you have the Maui Graphics Nuget in your project.